# Conditional Across Php and HTML

Tags: php, html

As a long time Java user, the idea of conditional statements is not new to me. I've recently begun learning php and came across a difficulty when trying to access data from a dropdown list and displaying it. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Bob's Auto Parts - Place an Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "/processorder.php" method="post"> 
        <table style = "border: opx;">
        <tr style = "background: #cccccc;">
            <td style = "width: 150px; text-align: center;">Item</td>
            <td style = "width: 15px; text-align: center;">Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tires</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "tireqty" size = "3" maxlength = "3" /></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Oil</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "oilqty" size = "3" maxlength = "3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spark Plugs</td>
        <td><input type = "text" name = "sparkqty" size = "3" maxlength = "3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>How did you find Bob's</td>
        <td><select name = "find">
        <option value = "a">I'm a regular customer</option>
        <option value = "b">TV advertising</option>
        <option value = "c">Phone directory</option>
        <option value = "d">Word of mouth</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = "2" style = "text-align: center;"><input type = 
 "submit" value = "Submit Order" /></td>
        </tr>           
        </table>
     </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding php:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bob's Auto Parts - Order Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bob's Auto Parts</h1>
<h2>Order Results</h2>
    <?php
        echo "<p>Order processed at: ";
        echo date('H:i, jS F Y');
        echo "</p>";

        // create short variable names
        $tireqty = $_POST['tireqty'];
        $oilqty = $_POST['oilqty'];
        $sparkqty = $_POST['sparkqty'];

        echo '<p>Your order is as follows: </p>';
        echo htmlspecialchars($tireqty). ' tires<br / >';
        echo htmlspecialchars($oilqty). ' bottles of oil<br / >';
        echo htmlspecialchars($sparkqty). ' spark plugs<br / >';

        /* is the same as...

        echo '<p>Your order is as follows: </p>';
        echo htmlspecialchars($tireqty); echo ' tires<br / >';
        echo htmlspecialchars($oilqty); echo ' bottles of oil<br / >';
        echo htmlspecialchars($sparkqty); echo ' spark plugs<br / >';

        */

        $totalqty = 0;
        $totalqty = $tireqty + $oilqty + $sparkqty;
        echo "<p>Items ordered: ".$totalqty."<br />";
        $totalamount = 0; 

        define('TIREPRICE', 100); 
        define('OILPRICE', 10);
        define('SPARKPRICE', 4); 

        $totalamount = $tireqty * TIREPRICE +
                       $oilqty * OILPRICE +
                       $sparkqty * SPARKPRICE;

        echo "Subtotal: $".number_format($totalamount, 2)."<br />"  ;

        $taxrate = 0.10; // local sales tax is 10% 
        $totalamount = $totalamount * (1 + $taxrate); 
        echo "Total including tax: $".number_format($totalamount, 2)."</p>";
        echo '$find'; 

        /* good for making sure forms are filled out...

        echo 'isset($tireqty): '.isset($tireqty).'<br />';
        echo 'isset($nothere): '.isset($nothere).'<br />';
        echo 'empty($tireqty): '.empty($tireqty).'<br />';
        echo 'empty($nothere): '.empty($nothere).'<br />'; 

        */


        if ($find == "a"){
                echo "<p>Regular Customer</p>";
        }

        elseif ($find == "b"){
                echo "<p>Customer referred by TV advert</p>";
        }

        elseif ($find == "c"){
                echo "<p>Customer referred by phone directory</p>";
        }

        elseif ($find == "d"){
                echo "<p>Customer referred by word of mouth</p>"; 
        }

        else {
                echo "<p>We do not know how this customer found us</p>";            
        }
    ?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Simply put, the results page always displays what is contained in the "else" statement, even when another option is pressed. Any advice/suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where does `$find` come from? Do you have a form you submit?

Comment: Is this the whole code?

Comment: Try echoing `$find` and seeing what its value is, if it's not what you expected, you should be able to figure out why.

Comment: No. There's a lot of other stuff and so I put the relevant parts. The other pieces of code work they way they are supposed to (from the html to the php file), so it's not that kind of issue.

Comment: There is a submit form in the html that links to the php, yes.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including your form and the PHP you use to process it.

Comment: form elements require an array POST/GET and we don't know what the form's method is and if there is an array assigned to the `$find` variable.

Comment: seeing the edit, there is no array assigned to that variable and as a side note: `echo '$find'` that won't echo out in single quotes.

Comment: I can't seem to find where you assign a value to `$find` from the `<select>` element

Comment: It's assigned where it says value = "letter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer here to check whether you missed something. I have tested this already and its working as is.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>How did you find Bob's</td>
            <td>
                <select name = "find">
                    <option value = "a">I'm a regular customer</option>
                    <option value = "b">TV advertising</option>
                    <option value = "c">Phone directory</option>
                    <option value = "d">Word of mouth</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $find = $_POST['find'];
        if ($find == "a"){
            echo "<p>Regular Customer</p>";
        }

        elseif ($find == "b"){
                echo "<p>Customer referred by TV advert</p>";
        }

        elseif ($find == "c"){
                echo "<p>Customer referred by phone directory</p>";
        }

        elseif ($find == "d"){
                echo "<p>Customer referred by word of mouth</p>"; 
        }

        else {
                echo "<p>We do not know how this customer found us</p>";            
        }
    }
?>
```